# How do I recurse DOM nodes to an arbitrary depth in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, recursion

I am really having trouble getting my head around crossbrowser recursion in the DOM. I want to get only the text content of a node, but not any HTML tags or other information. Through trial and error, I found that the textContent and innerText attributes don't hold across all browsers, so I have to use the data attribute.

Now the function I have so far is this:

```
    getTextContentXBrowser: function(nodeIn) {
        // Currently goes down two levels. Need to abstract further to handle arbitrary number of levels
        var tempString = '';
        for (i=0, len=nodeIn.childNodes.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (nodeIn.childNodes[i].firstChild !== null) {
                tempString += nodeIn.childNodes[i].firstChild.data;
            } else {
                if (nodeIn.childNodes[i].data && nodeIn.childNodes[i].data !== '\n') {
                    tempString += nodeIn.childNodes[i].data;
                }
            }
        }
        return tempString;
    },
```

It's written in object notation, but otherwise it's a pretty standard unremarkable function. It goes down two levels, which is almost good enough for what I want to do, but I want to "set it and forget it" if possible.

I've been at it for four hours and I haven't been able to abstract this to an arbitrary number of levels. Is recursion even my best choice here? Am I missing a better option? How would I convert the above function to recurse?

Thanks for any help!

Update: I rewrote it per dsfq's model, but for some reason, it goes one level down and is unable to go back up afterwards. I realized that my problem previously was that I wasn't concatenating in the second if clause, but this seems to have stopped me short of the goal. Here is my updated function:

```
    getTextContentXBrowser: function(nodeIn) {
        var tempString = '';
        for (i=0, len=nodeIn.childNodes.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (nodeIn.childNodes[i].data) {
                tempString += nodeIn.childNodes[i].data;
            } else if (nodeIn.childNodes[i].firstChild) {
                tempString += this.getTextContentXBrowser(nodeIn.childNodes[i]);
            }
        }
        return tempString.replace(/ /g,'').replace(/\n/g,'');
    },
```

Anyone see what I'm missing?

Comment: Yea, you'll want to use recursion. However, what you're doing isn't recursion.

Comment: My choice would be recursion, well depending whether i expect the node to be deeply nested or not. If it's nested in dom say 10 levels or more i rather work out another solution. If you got to traverse the whole page DOM to find a node using recursion is maybe a killer.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Right. I'm aware that the function I have doesn't use recursion. But I can't figure out how to make it recurse.

Comment: See [Recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) - the function needs to *call itself* (or a co-recursive function) in the recursive case.

Comment: @ITomas: Thanks! I don't anticipate a whole lotta levels. Probably a maximum of three.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered doing this with jQuery?

```
getTextContentXBrowser: function(nodeIn) {
    return $(nodeIn).text();
}
```

As simple as that!

Comment: Thanks! Can't do it with jQuery - the bandwidth hit is too large for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

It can be really simple function calling itself to to replace nodes with its contents. For example:

```
function flatten(node) {
    for (var c = node.childNodes, i = c.length; i--;) {
        if (c[i].nodeType == 1) {
            c[i].parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(flatten(c[i]).innerHTML), c[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Looks like in your case you `getTextContentXBrowser` is a method of some object, so you will need to call it from inside itself properly (in my example I just use function).

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7tyYA/

Note that this function replaces nodes with a text in place. If you want a function that just returns a text without modifying actual node right away consider this example with another version of the script:

#### Demo 2: http://jsfiddle.net/7tyYA/1/

Comment: This nodeType == 1 part, I was thinking about using this earlier - is it cross-browser safe?

Comment: Yes, 100% cross browser. This is a core of DOM spec, supported by all vendors.

Comment: The problem I see in this code is that you're replacing the existing DOM tree with text. The original function just returns the text, doesn't change the DOM. Apart from that, it does its job.

Comment: Oh, it's true, I replace nodes, while the original returns a text.. Need to fix it.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried to implement this, but for some reason (likely my unfamiliarity with the DOM more than recursion) it seems to be unable to trace back up levels. I've updated my function above. Any insight?